# set the value of Entry using Binding [Xamarin.Forms]

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to set the value of Entry using Binding. My simple question is that, how may I use the value of C# class variable in XML page through Binding.?

Here is the screenshot of my XML Page
[image]

Here is the screenshot of Class File
[image]

is it possible in Xamarin.Forms (Portable)?

The simple logic for this requirement is that, in future if I have to change the color or text or anything then I don't have to do to each file and change text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only bind to public properties.

XAML:

```
<Entry Color="{Binding EntryColor}" />
```

C#:

```
public Color EntryColor { get { return Color.White; } }
```

Comment: and how to assing this in code behand file? I mean, how can I bridge to both?

Comment: myEntry.SetBinding(Entry.ColorProperty, new Binding("EntryColor"));

Comment: I thought, I can bind all the Entry with the single line of code. I have to write SetBinding for each control. right?